# xctest iOS UI test - tapping link not working

Tags: swift, xcode, xctest

My application looks very much like this:

[How to tap on specific part/Words of a string statement in XCode UI Tests without using coordinate method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42267556/how-to-tap-on-specific-part-words-of-a-string-statement-in-xcode-ui-tests-withou)

Where I have a sentence like below:

"Here's a sentence with a *link* users can click on"

The "link" above opens another page.

My goal of the test is to test the behaviour when users tap on this link.

When I do `print(XCUIApplication().debugDescription)`

TextView, 0x1xxxe120, {{22.0, 636.7}, {323.5, 73.1}}, label: 'Here's a sentence with a *link* users can click on'

Link, 0x103xxxe7e0, {{25.0, 702.2}, {314.5, 51.6}}, label: 'link'

However below code doesn't open the page.

```
let textLink = app.links["link"]
textLink.tap()
```

Any advise would be appreaciated.